# jQuery on('change') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm working with ajax forms where based on a select element value change, an ajax request is sent to the server, then in response a json string is returned. I build the second form based on this json string. the problem is I want to make a third select element based on second select element value change(the one that is generated via javascript). in this situation when i want to work with **change** event, it doesn't work:

My javascript code so far:

```
jQuery("#make").on('change',function(){
        var value = jQuery(this).val();
        if(value != 0)
        {
            jQuery.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('ajax/get/models'); ?>",
                {makeId:value},
                function(data){
                    if(data != "false")
                    {
                        var modelsSelect = document.createElement('select');
                        modelsSelect.setAttribute('name','model');
                        modelsSelect.setAttribute('id','model');
                        var modelOption =  document.createElement('option');
                        modelOption.setAttribute('value',0);
                        modelOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode("sample text"));
                        modelsSelect.appendChild(modelOption);
                        jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
                            var modelOption =  document.createElement('option');
                            modelOption.setAttribute('value',item.id);
                            modelOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.model.toString()));
                            modelsSelect.appendChild(modelOption);
                        });
                        jQuery("#model").replaceWith(modelsSelect);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            var modelsSelect = document.createElement('select');
            modelsSelect.setAttribute('name','model');
            modelsSelect.setAttribute('id','model');
            modelsSelect.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
            var modelOption =  document.createElement('option');
            modelOption.setAttribute('value',0);
            modelOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode("sample text"));
            modelsSelect.appendChild(modelOption);
            jQuery("#model").replaceWith(modelsSelect);
            return false;
        }
    });
    jQuery("#model").on('change',function(){
        alert("change");// THIS DOES NOT WORK
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a delegated event handler for that as you're replacing `#model` with a new dynamic element :

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#model', function(){
    alert("change");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: that's right. but can you please explain the reason for this?

Comment: and I should use this syntax for each element I want to handle its events?

Comment: You should replace `document` with the closest non dynamic parent of #model, and yes, for dynamically added elements, this is the way to delegate event handlers.

Comment: Also, before I answered I started rewriting much of your code, but it was too much work, but here's what I did -> http://jsfiddle.net/knDa2/ if it helps you out ?